# ¿Es posible tomar datos de una base de datos SQL Server para después compararlos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, consola

Buen día.

Tengo una base de datos en SQL Server y debo tomar ciertos datos para después compararlos con los de un archivo de texto. Es decir, tengo mi siguiente base:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la cual necesito tomar primero el dato RfcEmpresa, compararlo con RFC de un archivo de texto si estos son iguales entonces debe hacer otra comparación tomando el dato Serie y validar si es igual al del archivo de texto, si estos son iguales entonces me tiene que imprimir el dato RutaEmpresa.
Este es mi código hasta ahora:

```
conexionbd conexionbd = new conexionbd();

        string sCon = conexionbd.CadenaConexion();
        string sel;
        string txtSerie = "NX001";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            sel = "Select RfcEmpresa from Config where Serie = '" + txtSerie.ToString() +"'";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sel, con);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                string txtRFC = "AAA010101AAA";
                string rfc = myReader["RfcEmpresa"].ToString();
                if (rfc == txtRFC)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rfc);
                }  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        
        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Hasta ahora me imprime el RFC de la base si este es igual al del archivo txt (por el momento los datos de txt los pongo fijos, estoy realizando pruebas).
Me falta tomar el dato Serie de la base para hacer la comparación, ya no se como continuar.
Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para mejorar es bienvenida.

Comment: Sería realizar lo mismo pero con Serie: myReader["Serie"].ToString() y compararlo con el del archivo de texto. Esto sería dentro del if. ¿Cuál es el problema o por qué no sabes como continuar?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Carlos, si agrego un Serie: myReader["Serie"].ToString();, como me indicas, me genera un error.

Comment: Lo he resuelto, tuve un error en la cosulta, me faltaba agregar los campos a tomar, la consulta quedaría asi: sel = "Select RfcEmpresa,RutaEmpresa,Serie from Config where Serie = '" + txtSerie.ToString() +"'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas de lógica en tu código, con relación a la descripción que das:

- Comienzas diciendo que lo primero que tienes que comparar es el RFC, sin embargo, vas a traer el registro a la base de datos en base al número de serie (lo cual de por si ya es una comparación).
- Vas declarando las variables de lo que habría en el supuesto archivo de texto a medida que se desarrolla el código, pero en una implementación final, lo más probable es que leas toda la información del archivo en un mismo punto, por lo que es mejor declarar todas las variables en el mismo punto.
- Traes un solo campo de la base de datos, cuando podríamos traer todos los necesarios, lo cual es óptimo, pues el acceso a base de datos es *caro* en tiempo y recursos.

Además de esto:

- Tu código es vulnerable a la [inyección de SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), siempre que se va a procesar valores que vienen de fuera del programa, es mejor utilizar una consulta parametrizada para resolver este asunto.

Poniendo en un trozo de código la *solución* a los problemas mencionados arriba, quedaría algo como:

```
    conexionbd conexionbd = new conexionbd();
    string sCon = conexionbd.CadenaConexion();
    string txtSerie = "NX001";
    string txtRFC = "AAA010101AAA";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon);
    try {
        con.Open();
        string sel = "select Serie, RutaEmpresa from Config where RfcEmpresa = @RFC";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sel, con);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFC", txtRFC);
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while(myReader.Read()) {
            string dbSerie = myReader["Serie"].ToString();
            if (txtSerie == dbSerie) {
                Console.WriteLine("RFC:   " + txtRFC);
                Console.WriteLine("Serie: " + dbSerie);
                Console.WriteLine("Ruta:  " + myReader["RutaEmpresa"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    System.Console.ReadKey();
```

He evitado traer y comparar en c# el campo `RfcEmpresa`; esto resulta innecesario luego de obtener el resultado de la consulta porque ya se ha hecho en el motor de base de datos, que nos devuelve solo los registros para los que `RfcEmpresa` es igual a nuestro `txtRFC`.

El código está sin comentarios, porque creo que se explica solo. Si tienes duda de algo, dejame saber.

Comment: Hola @jachguate, agradezco la respuesta. Me has sido de gran ayuda, realice unos ajustes de acuerdo lo que me comentas y funciona correctamente.